# Scala http client for large files

Tags: scala, http

I need to write an HTTP client that will periodically download (and dump on disk) files that are much larger than the available memory.

What's the most appropriate strategies and HTTP client libraries for this task?

A plus for libs without bulky dependencies like Akka.

Comment: http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html Take a look, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I found a reasonable solution that **does not require adding any external dependencies**. Only Scala/Java standard libraries.

```
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File
new URL("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip") #> new File("/tmp/1gb.zip") !!
```

**Bonus**: add some headers and conditional get to the request

```
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

val url = new URL("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip")
val conn = url.openConnection
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/json")
conn.setIfModifiedSince(new Date().getTime - 1000*60*30)
url #> new File("/tmp/1gb.zip") !!
```

Comment: The above doesn't work until you do the whole express .run. Is there a way to track when the download is complete, by the way?

Comment: HI sscarduzio, thanks it work. Just wonder, where can I get more information about "#>" and "!!"?

Comment: Hi @carfield, what your are looking for is the sys.process  API in the Scala standard library: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/index.html